# How do I assign a memory limit for mySQL?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, memory

mysql tuner reports that mySQL can use 166% of installed ram, how do I limit RAM usage ?

> [!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 426.8M (166% of installed RAM)

Comment: You should also add some RAM. 256 MB is not very much.

Comment: @Tibor It's a cheap low end VPS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either configure

- All MyISAM
- All InnoDB
- Mixture of MyISAM and InnoDB

Before allocating memory to either engine, it is good to reflect on what caching goes with each Storage Engine

## Configuring for **MYISAM**

The main mechanism used is the key cache. It only caches index pages from .MYI files. To size your key cache, run the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(KBS/POWER(1024,
IF(PowerOf1024<0,0,IF(PowerOf1024>3,0,PowerOf1024)))+0.4999),
SUBSTR(' KMG',IF(PowerOf1024<0,0,
IF(PowerOf1024>3,0,PowerOf1024))+1,1))
recommended_key_buffer_size FROM
(SELECT LEAST(POWER(2,32),KBS1) KBS
FROM (SELECT SUM(index_length) KBS1
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE engine='MyISAM' AND
table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')) AA ) A,
(SELECT 2 PowerOf1024) B;
```

This will give the Recommended Setting for MyISAM Key Cache ([**key_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size)) given your current data set ([the query will cap the recommendation at 4G (4096M).](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size) For 32-bit OS, 4GB is the limit. For 64-bit, 8GB.

## Configuring for **InnoDB**

The main mechanism used is the InnoDB Buffer Pool. It caches data and index pages from InnoDB tables accessed. To size your InnoDB Buffer Pool, run the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(KBS/POWER(1024,
IF(PowerOf1024<0,0,IF(PowerOf1024>3,0,PowerOf1024)))+0.49999),
SUBSTR(' KMG',IF(PowerOf1024<0,0,
IF(PowerOf1024>3,0,PowerOf1024))+1,1)) recommended_innodb_buffer_pool_size
FROM (SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) KBS FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE engine='InnoDB') A,
(SELECT 2 PowerOf1024) B;
```

This will give the Recommended Setting for the size of the InnoDB Buffer Pool ([**innodb_buffer_pool_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)) given your current data set.

Don't forget to resize the InnoDB Log Files (ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1). MySQL Source Code places a cap of the combined sizes of all InnoDB Log Files must be < 4G (4096M). (NOTE: Percona Server binaries surpass this. I recently setup a large DB server with 4G for a single InnoDB Log File using [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size))

For the sake of simplicity, given just two log files, here is how you can size them:

- Step 1) add innodb_log_file_size=NNN to /etc/my.cnf
  (NNN should be 25% of innodb_buffer_pool_size or 2047M, whichever is smaller)
- Step 2) service mysql stop
- Step 3) rm /var/log/mysql/ib_logfile[01]
- Step 4) service mysql start (ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 are recreated)

## **CAVEAT**

At the End of both queries is a an Inline Query : `(SELECT 2 PowerOfTwo) B`

- `(SELECT 0 PowerOf1024)` gives the Setting in Bytes
- `(SELECT 1 PowerOf1024)` gives the Setting in Kilobytes
- `(SELECT 2 PowerOf1024)` gives the Setting in Megabytes
- `(SELECT 3 PowerOf1024)` gives the Setting in Gigabytes
- No powers less that 0 or greater than 3 is accepted

## **EPILOGUE**

There is no substitute for common sense. If you have limited memory, a mixture of storage engines, or a combination thereof, you will have to adjust for different scenarios.

If you have 2GB RAM and 16GB of InnoDB, allocate 512M as `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

If you have 2GB RAM and 4GB of MyISAM Indexes, allocate 512M as `key_buffer_size`.

If you have 2GB RAM and 4GB of MyISAM Indexes and 16GB InnoDB, allocate 512M as `key_buffer_size` and 512M as `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Possible scenarios are endless !!!

Remember, whatever you allocate for, leave enough RAM for DB Connections and the Operating System.

Answer (score 3):

You should tweak `key_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in your `my.cnf`, these two are the most important memory-related settings. To get your current values use `show variables like 'key_buffer_size';` and `show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';` in `mysql` command-line client.

Answer (score 3):

in case of Myisam Engine

**key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_connections**

this value gives the total possible memory that mysql can  consume.This should be less than your RAM or nearly 60 % of RAM.
incase of innodb **innodb_buffer_pool_size** should be less than your RAM or 60% of your ram

Tune above values,so that RAM usage will be 60% of your RAM.